# Should enums be exported out of dll or not?

Tags: c++, dll, enums, export, dllexport

The project (in cpp) we are working on exports *enum* types from the dll. In exporting we are having some issues so I wanted to ask something related to **exporting** *enum* type.

I think that *enum's* behave like 'kind of' constants, so they do not provide any 'functionality' to the user. So, can we omit the exporting of *enum's* ?

OR

Are there some functionalities (other than behaving as constants) that the *enum's* provide to the end-user that makes it necessary to export them ?

More details :

We have a header file containing following piece of code:

```
enum DECL_BASE logical_state
{
    LOGICAL_TRUE,
    LOGICAL_FALSE,
    LOGICAL_DEFAULT
};

//DECL_BASE is __declspec(dllexport)
```

This code compiles fine with no warnings or errors. I just wanted to know that what is/are the use(s) of exporting this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details about your question?

Comment: Dllexport/dllimport only works on something that has an address: variables, member functions etc. You cannot export something that has no address, and enum types don't have addresses. They are basically compiler-time constants - you just need to make sure to use same definition of enum type while compiling dll and dll users.

Comment: ` LOGICAL_DEFAULT` ? Shouldn't that be [`FILE_NOT_FOUND`](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_) ?

Comment: @MSalters  The whole project compiled fine! My concern is - for what good purpose one would try to export this.

Answer (score 9):

Usually for using the enums and constants of a dll, for calling the exported interfaces of the dll, we only have to declare those enums and constants in the provided dll's header file(s). No export calling convention is needed for them.

Please give more clarity to your issue, if the above comment doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I think we would remove these exports now.