# How to DllImport enums in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, enums

I've compiled a dll in c++ with an enum that needs to be use in a c++ project and a c# project. With the c++ project there were no problems but in c# pops up that DllImport can only be used for methods

I've thought about functions to solve this problems but it's all a mess. I simply need to access c++ enums from c#

this is the c++ enum inside the dll:

```cpp
enum DLL_PUBLIC ByteCode
{
    // Stuffs...
};
```

and this is how i tried to import it in c#:

```cs
[DllImport("ByteCodes.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
enum ByteCodes;
```

Here i got that `DllImport` can only be used for methods but i need it for enums. What can i do?

Comment: C++ and C# are not always easy to interoperate. They are quite different languages with quite different ways of doing things - and there's no standardized ABI.

Comment: @JesperJuhl So i should just create a 2nd DLL for c# and copy-paste the code every time i edit the enum? it's not all that work, it's just a bit messy but if it is the only way...

Comment: @Bonfra04 you don't have to rewrite all the code in C#, just the enum declaration (see my answer).

Comment: DllExport is for functions, not for values, so export on enum is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-declare the members of the enum as simple `const int` values in the C# side. Or you can simply redeclare the enum, making sure to define the members with `= 1`, etc. to match the C++ declaration.

Comment: Yes i guess i'll go with this

Comment: @Bonfra04 It's not that you have much choice. Enums are [not exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400469/should-enums-be-exported-out-of-dll-or-not#comment68052905_40400469) anyway. Redeclaring then on the managed side is *the* way, be it as constants or as enums.